# What's the subject in meaning of 'providing the quantity of light'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Innovation has made it possible to work for a fraction of a second so as to be able to afford to turn on an electric lamp for an hour, **providing the quantity of light that would have required a whole day’s work** if you had to make it yourself by collecting and refining sesame oil or lamb fat to burn in a simple lamp, as much of humanity did in the not so distant past.
> From *How Innovation Works: And Why It Flourishes in Freedom* by Matt Ridley

What is the subject (in terms of meaning) of ‘providing the quantity of light’? That is, *who* or *what* provides the quantity of light that would have required a whole day’s work?

1. The subject of 'to work for a fraction of a second', which is for example, ‘you’, 'they', ‘a person’ or ‘people’.
2. The preceding to-infinitive clause: 'to work for a fraction of a second so as to be able to afford to turn on an electric lamp or an hour'
3. 'Innovation'

Answer (score 2):

What actually provides the light is clearly the electric lamp, so what this clause modifies is the infinitive phrase

> to turn on an electric lamp for an hour.

It's also true that "innovation" has provided the light, albeit more indirectly. However, the sentence structure becomes quite convoluted if you try to make this clause modify "innovation".

Comment: Precisely. As usual, a resultative verb phrase has a causative subject, in this case a clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, I also assumed it would be a clause. But I couldn't decide which clause is appropriate. Do you think the 'to turn on ~' clause is the answer?

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I still don't get why only the 'to turn on an electric lamp for an hour' clause is right as a subject and why the 'to work for a fraction of a second so as to be able to afford to turn on an electric lamp or an hour' clause is not. I feel that even though we work for a fraction of a second now, we can get the quantity of light that would have required a whole day’s work in the past and this shows their causality well. Would you help me with this thought if I am wrong?

Comment: The reason that I don't think "work" fits that well for the subject of this clause is semantic, not grammatical. The work doesn't by itself provide the light; the electric lamp does.

Comment: @PeterShor I appreciate your kind answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here "providing" is modifying the entire preceding clause, much like an adverb. What provides the quantity of light is **the fact that** innovation has made it possible to work for a fraction of a second so as to be able to afford to turn on an electric lamp for an hour.

Comment: Thank you but why do you think the entire preceding clause is more appropriate for what provides the quantity of light than only the preceding to-infinitive clause starting with 'to work'?